The vertices of a triangle are three random points on a unit circle. The side lengths are, in random order, $a,b,c$. Show that $P(ab>c)=\frac12$
The vertices of a triangle are three unifomly random points on a unit circle. The side lengths are, in random order, $a,b,c$.
There is a convoluted proof that $P(ab>c)=\frac12$. But since the probability is so simple, I am looking for an intuitive explanation, for example one that utilizes symmetry.
(If an intuitive explanation can be given, then I will remove this question from my list of probability questions that have answer $\frac12$ but resist intuitive explanation.)

Somehow this problem seems "ill posed"  to me  for the following reason. We are asked to compare two quantities that  have different physical meanings since are measured by different units.:  $ab$ is measured in units of area while  $c$ is measured  in units of distance.

@LiviuNicolaescu I don't think that the question is "ill posed". Instead of a unit circle, you can formulate it for an arbitrary circle of radius $r$ and replace $c$ with $rc$, and the measure units are right.

I think it is worthwhile to remark that the OP generalized the result to $P(ab<kc)=\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan k$ for any $k>0$. It is contained in the original post at MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4878430

I added a standard probability proof that $P(ab<kc)=\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan k$ for any $k>0$. The proof boils down to the fact that the average of independent random variables with standard Cauchy distribution also has standard Cauchy distribution.

One can use basic probability theory to prove that
$$P(ab<kc)=\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan k,\qquad k>0.$$
Without loss of generality, the vertices opposite the sides $a,b,c$ are
$$A=e^{2i\beta},\qquad B=e^{-2i\alpha},\qquad C=1,$$
where $\alpha,\beta\in(0,\pi)$ are independent random variables with uniform distribution. Then
$$a=BC=2\sin\alpha,\qquad b=AC=2\sin\beta,\qquad c=AB=2|\sin(\alpha+\beta)|,$$
and hence
$$ab<kc
\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
2\sin\alpha\sin\beta<k|\sin(\alpha+\beta)|
\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
\frac{1}{k}<\left|\frac{\cot\alpha+\cot\beta}{2}\right|.$$
Now $\cot\alpha$ and $\cot\beta$ are independent random variables with standard Cauchy distribution, hence their average also has standard Cauchy distribution. So if $X\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ is a random variable with uniform distribution, then
$$P(ab<kc)=P\left(\frac{1}{k}<|\cot X|\right)=P(|\tan X|<k)=P(|X|<\arctan k)=\frac{2\arctan k}{\pi}.$$

Very pretty. So the key is to not ever draw a picture.

The following argument is less or more the same as that of Iosif Pinelis, but with less computations and the symmetry is rather explicit. It may be explained without complex numbers, but the explanation I have in mind is rather longer.
We use complex coordinates on the unit circle. Let one vertex be 1, other two by $x$ and $y$, so a random triangle has "coordinates" $(x,y)$, coordinates are uniform on the circle and independent. Partition all triangles onto quadruples of the form $(x,y),(ix,-iy),(-ix,iy),(-x,-y)$. I claim that (in general position) exactly two out of these four triangles satisfy $ab>c$, and two satisfy $ab<c$, where $c=|x-y|$, $a=|1-x|$, $b=|1-y|$. The main combinatorial reason for that is the following
Observation. If $A,B,C,D$ are non-zero real numbers, and $AC<0$ or $BD<0$, then exactly two of the four numbers $AB,BC,CD,DA$ are positive.
We rewrite the inequality $ab<c$ as $$|x-y|^2>|1-x|^2\cdot |1-y|^2\Leftrightarrow -\frac{(x-y)^2}{xy}>\frac{(1-x)^2(1-y)^2}{xy} \Leftrightarrow \\
0>\frac{(1+xy-x-y-i(x-y))(1+xy-x-y+i(x-y))}{xy}=:AB,$$
where I denote $xy=z^2$, $A=(1+xy-x(1+i)-y(1-i))/z$, $B=(1+xy-x(1-i)-y(1+i))/z$. Note that the numbers $A,B$ are real (and in general position non-zero), and for three other triangles analogous inequalities read as $0>BC$, $0>CD$, $0>DA$, where $C=(1+xy-x(-1-i)-y(-1+i))/z$ and $D=(1+xy-x(-1+i)-y(-1-i))/z$.
To apply the observation, it remains to prove that $AC<0$ or $BD<0$. Well, if $(x/z)(1+i)=u+iv$ (for real $u,v$), then $A,C=(1+xy)/z\pm 2u$ and $B,D=(1+xy)/z\pm 2v$. We have $u^2+v^2=2$, thus $\max(|u|,|v|)\geqslant 1$, and so the result.

A proof from pure geometry
On a unit circle with centre $O$, draw parallel chords $PQ$ and $P'Q'$ such that $PQ'\perp P'Q$. Chord $MN$ is parallel to $PQ$ and passes through $R$, the intersection of $PQ'$ and $P'Q$. Minor arc $MN$ is colored red. $\alpha=\angle POQ$ and $\beta=\angle P'OQ'$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are convex.

We use the fact that, for a triangle with side lengths $a,b,c$ inscribed in a unit circle, $\text{area}=\frac{abc}{4}$.
$\therefore P(ab<c)=P\left(\frac{abc}{4}<\frac{c^2}{4}\right)=P\left(\text{area}<\frac{c^2}{4}\right)$
Let $P$ be the first chosen vertex of the triangle, and $Q$ the second chosen vertex. Let $PQ=c$. If $ab\color{red}{<}c$, the third chosen point must lie on the red arc. (This is because the inscribed triangle's area must be smaller than $\frac{c^2}{4}$, which is the area of $\triangle PQR$.)
So $P(ab\color{red}{<}c)$ is the proportion of the red arc length to the circumference of the circle, averaged as $\color{red}{\alpha}$ goes from $0^\circ$ to $180^\circ$.
Now instead let $P'$ be the first chosen vertex, and $Q'$ the second chosen vertex. Let $P'Q'=c$. If $ab\color{red}{>}c$, the third chosen point must lie on the red arc. (This is because the inscribed triangle's area must be greater than $\frac{c^2}{4}$, which is the area of $\triangle P'Q'R$.)
So $P(ab\color{red}{>}c)$ is the proportion of the red arc length to the circumference of the circle, averaged as $\color{red}{\beta}$ goes from $0$ to $180^\circ$, or by symmetry, as $\color{red}{\beta}$ goes from $180^\circ$ to $0^\circ$.
Obviously, $\alpha+\beta=180^\circ$ ($\angle POP'=2\times \angle PQ'P=90^\circ$).
Therefore the red arc length averaged as $\alpha$ goes from $0^\circ$ to $180^\circ$, is exactly the same as the red arc length averaged as $\beta$ goes from $180^\circ$ to $0^\circ$.
Therefore $P(ab<c)=P(ab>c)$. And since $P(ab<c)=1-P(ab>c)$, we have $P(ab>c)=\frac12.$

Very beautiful! The area formula is also proved in a comment by GH below: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/468355/the-vertices-of-a-triangle-are-three-random-points-on-a-unit-circle-the-side-le/468617#comment1216394_468434

Without loss of generality, the three points on the unit circle are $1,e^{is},e^{it}$, where $s$ and $t$ are uniformly and independently distributed on the interval $[0,2\pi]$, so that $a=|e^{is}-1|$, $b=|e^{it}-1|$, $c=|e^{is}-e^{it}|$.
Then the condition $ab>c$ can be rewritten as
$$|u|<h(v):=\cos^{-1}g(v) \tag{10}\label{10}$$
for
$$(u,v):=\Big(\frac{s-t}2,\frac{s+t}2\Big)\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\times[0,2\pi],$$
where
$$g(v):=\frac{\cos v+\sqrt{2-\cos^2 v}}2;$$
see details on \eqref{10} at the end of this answer.
Here is the set of all pairs $(v,u)\in[0,2\pi]\times[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ satisfying condition \eqref{10}:

Note the symmetries
$$h(2\pi-v)=h(v)\quad\text{and especially}\quad h(v)+h(\pi-v)=\pi/2;\tag{20}\label{20}$$
see details on this at the end of the answer.
Also, the Jacobian $J:=\frac{\partial(s,t)}{\partial(u,v)}$ is $2$.
The probability (say $p$) in question is $\dfrac A{(2\pi)^2}$, where $A$ is the area of the set of all $(s,t)\in[0,2\pi]^2$ satisfying the condition $ab>c$, so that
$$A=2\times2\int_0^{2\pi}dv\,h(v)
=8\int_0^\pi dv\,h(v)=8\int_0^\pi dv\,h(\pi-v) \\
=8\times\frac12 \int_0^\pi dv\,[h(v)+h(\pi-v)]
=8\times\frac12 \,\pi\times\pi/2=2\pi^2. $$
(This result is "obvious" from the above picture, because $A$ is $J$ times the depicted area (that is, twice the depicted area), whereas the depicted area is half of the area $2\pi\times\pi$ of the rectangle enclosing the depicted area.)
So, $p=\dfrac{2\pi^2}{(2\pi)^2}=\dfrac12$. $\quad\Box$

Details on \eqref{10}: Note that $a^2=(e^{is}-1)(e^{-is}-1)=2(1-\cos s)$. Similarly, $b^2=2(1-\cos t)$ and $c^2=(e^{i(s-t)}-1)(e^{-i(s-t)}-1)=2(1-\cos(s-t))$. So, $ab>c$ can be rewritten as
$2(1-\cos s)(1-\cos t)>1-\cos(s-t)$ or as $2(1-(\cos s+\cos t)+\cos s\,\cos t)>1-\cos(s-t)$. Now use the identities $\cos s+\cos t=2\cos u\cos v$ and $2\cos s\,\cos t=\cos2u+\cos2v$, $\cos 2x=2\cos^2x-1$, and $s-t=2u$ to rewrite $ab>c$ as $\cos u\ge g(v)$, which is equivalent to \eqref{10}, because $0\le g\le1$.
Details on the identity $h(v)+h(\pi-v)=\pi/2$ in \eqref{20}: Since $0\le g\le1$, \eqref{10} implies $0\le h\le\pi/2$. So,
for
$$f(v):=g(\pi-v)=\frac{-\cos v+\sqrt{2-\cos^2 v}}2$$
we have
$$0\le\cos(\pi/2-h(\pi-v))=\sin(h(\pi-v)) \\ 
=\sin(\cos^{-1} f(v))
=\sqrt{1-f(v)^2}=g(v)=\cos h(v). $$
Using again the fact that $0\le h\le\pi/2$, we get $\pi/2-h(\pi-v)=h(v)$, as desired.

Responding to the comment that "$\sqrt{1-f(v)^2}=g(v)$ is true but not obviously true", here is a symmetry proof of that: Letting $y:=\cos v$, $x_+:=g(v)=\frac{y+\sqrt{2-y^2}}2$, and $x_-:=f(v)=\frac{-y+\sqrt{2-y^2}}2$, we have $x_+ +x_-=\sqrt{2-y^2}$ and $2x_+ x_-=1-y^2$, so that
$g(v)^2+f(v)^2=x_+^2+x_-^2=(x_+ +x_-)^2-2x_+ x_-=(2-y^2)-(1-y^2)=1$. Therefore and because $g(v)\ge0$, we get $\sqrt{1-f(v)^2}=g(v)$.

Is there an obvious reason why $h(v)+h(\pi-v)=\pi/2$ ? (If so, then we can translate the upper boundary of the blue region to an odd function, and then by symmetry the probability is $1/2$.)

@Dan : I have added this detail as well.

Thank you, it is a nice proof. But, for me, it is not intuitive. (For example, $\sqrt{1-f(v)^2}=g(v)$ is true but not obviously true.) Maybe there is no intuitive explanation for the fact that $P=1/2$.

@Dan : I am glad you liked the proof, even if it does not seem intuitive enough for you. Can there be a proof that there is no proof here intuitive enough for you? :-) Of course, the crucial fact here is the symmetry $h(v)+h(\pi-v)=\pi/2$. So, the question may be whether there is a more intuitive proof of this symmetry, or do you disagree with this?

I agree that the symmetry of $h(v)+h(\pi-v)=\pi/2$ is the essense of your proof. Maybe there are other approaches that no one has thought of yet. The fact that the probability is $1/2$, makes me wonder if there exists a proof that boils down to choosing one half of the circle or the other (or something like that) so that the $1/2$ becomes obvious.

Denoting the angles corresponding to edges of side lengths $a,b,c$ with $A,B,C$ respectively, by the sine law:
$$\frac{a}{\sin A}=\frac{b}{\sin B}=\frac{c}{\sin C}=2.$$
Thus $c>ab$ amounts to $\sin(C)>2\sin(A)\sin(B)$. Replacing the LHS with $\sin(A+B)$ and the RHS with $\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)$, we can rephrase $c>ab$ as $\sin(A+B)+\cos(A+B)>\cos(A-B)$, or equivalently $\sqrt{2}\cos\left(A+B-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)>\cos(A-B)$. Denoting $A-B$ by $y$ and $A+B$ by $x$, they are subject only to $|y|<x<\pi$; and one should investigate the region $\sqrt{2}\cos\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)>\cos(y)$. Changing $y$ to $-y$ won't change the inequalities. So WLOG, we may assume that $0<y<x<\pi$. Notice that $\sqrt{2}\cos\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)>\cos(y)$ automatically holds when $x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ because then the LHS is larger than $1$. As for the case of $x\in\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right)$, one should have
$y>\cos^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\cos\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)$. All in all, we have the picture below in which the ratio of the area of the yellow area to the area of the triangle $0<y<x<\pi$ is equal to $\Bbb{P}(c>ab)$.

We conclude that
$$\Bbb{P}(c>ab)=\frac{1}{2}\Leftrightarrow\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\cos^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\cos\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right){\rm{d}}x=\frac{\pi^2}{4}\approx 2.467401.$$
The value of this integral according to Wolfram Alpha:

Finally, I compute
$\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\cos^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\cos\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right){\rm{d}}x
=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\cos^{-1}\left(\cos x+\sin x\right){\rm{d}}x$
using symmetry. Notice that with the change of variable $x\mapsto\frac{3\pi}{2}-x$:
$$
\begin{split}
&\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\cos^{-1}\left(\cos x+\sin x\right){\rm{d}}x\\
&=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\cos^{-1}\left(\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-x\right)+\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-x\right)\right){\rm{d}}x
=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\cos^{-1}\left(-\cos x-\sin x\right){\rm{d}}x\\
&=\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\left[\pi-\cos^{-1}\left(\cos x+\sin x\right)\right]{\rm{d}}x=\frac{\pi^2}{2}-\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\cos^{-1}\left(\cos x+\sin x\right){\rm{d}}x.
\end{split}
$$
Hence
$\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\cos^{-1}\left(\cos x+\sin x\right){\rm{d}}x=\frac{\pi^2}{4}.$

Here is an elementary proof using basic trigonometry for the more general formula $p(ab<rc)=\frac{2 \arctan(r)}{\pi}.$
Fixing one point on a circle of radius $r$ and placing the other two at angles $a$ and $b$ consecutively the condition becomes $4r^2\sin{a}\sin{b}>2r\sin{(b+a)}$ or  $2r\sin{a}\sin{b}>|\sin{(b+a)}|$ with $a,b\in[0,\pi]$. Expanding we find that $2r\tan a\tan b>|\tan a+\tan b|$ or equivalently $2r>|\cot a+\cot b|$ and hence $2r>|\tan (a^{'})+\tan (b^{'})|$ where $a^{'},b^{'}\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. Plotting the region, illustrated here for $r=1$, we have:

and focussing on the curve:

We see that we can compute the probability $p$ of point lying in the region by taking half the area of rectangle OABC assuming that we can show the curve is suitably symmetric.
This is easy to do by setting $s(x,y)=\tan(\frac{x+y}{2})+\tan(\frac{y-x}{2})$ and noting that the region $OABC$ is mapped to $[0,\pi]\times[0,2\arctan(r)]$ and the curve to $s(x,y)=2r$. The plot becomes

Using the tangent addition formula it is easy to prove that $$s(x,y)=2r \iff S(\pi-x,2 \arctan(r)-y)=2r$$ with $x\in[0,\pi]$,$y\in[0,\pi/2]$.
Hence probability $p=$ area OABC$/d^2$ with $d=\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{2}$ and $|OA|=|(\arctan(r),\arctan(r))|=\sqrt{2}\arctan(r)$.
Hence we obtain $$p= \frac{d \sqrt{2}\arctan(r)}{d^2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}\arctan(r)}{ \frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{2}}= \frac{2 \arctan(r)}{\pi}.$$

We use the formula (from en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumcircle#Other_properties ):
diameter = a * b * c /  (  2 * area )
In our case diameter = 2 and we get:
4 * area = a * b * c
If h is the height of the triangle over the base c then area = h * c / 2 and we get:
2 * h = a * b
We are then interested in the probability h < c / 2.
If the side of the triangle giving the length c is fixed then the set of points giving a triangle satisfying the inequality is an "open" circle segment. All "open" circle segments can be obtained in this way from unique starting triangle side.
Now consider two triangle sides giving complementary circle segments. With probability one an extra point makes exactly one of the two completed triangles satisfy the inequality. And I think it should be easy to finish the argument 
Instead of writing a bunch of formulas that I honestly feel are just tedious I give you a picture

The black circle segment is the part giving triangles satisfying the inequality (th red line is the side giving with length c). The roundish things are supposed to be circles Note that you can make a larger circle at the top giving the complementary segment (using this symmetry there are many ways to exploit symmetry to get the 1/2 probability, I can expand but if already this part is not understandable I again do not really see the point). Hope this gives enough intuition for the problem. For me the entire point of this question was to avoid doing lots of technical computations :)

(i) "The set of points P_2 satisfying this forms an open circle segment" -- I think this set is the union of two arcs of the circle. (ii) "all circle segments arise in this way from unique pairs $P_1,P_3$. Similarly the all circle segments also arise in this way from points $P'_2$ where the equality goes the other way. Setting up the integrals to compute these will then be identical and the probability will be a half" -- I can hardly understand anything here. Can you explain this quite formally? (iii) Do you have a reference to an intuitive proof of your initial identity?

(i) No I think it is one: Let C be the circle where $P_1P_3$ is a diameter. Consider the diagonal of C that is orthogonal to $P_1P_3$, one of the endpoints of this diagonal is outside the unit circle and the other one $P$ is inside. The line paralell to $P_1P_3$ trough $P$ gives the endpoints of the segment. (ii) Yes this is confusing, I will clarify. (iii) Not really, anyway I think a better point to start is the formula of diameter in terms of area in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumcircle#Other_properties

I still hardly understand anything in your answer after "h < c / 2". Also, I hardly understand anything in part (i) of your comment. In particular, what do you mean by "diagonal of C"? Again, can you write your argument formally -- just in terms of sets,  their elements, functions, and the like? Also, without things like "I think it should be easy to finish the argument"?

@IosifPinelis The identity $2rh=ab$ is easy to see by writing it in the form $h/a=(b/2)/r$. This form of the identity follows by exhibiting two similar right triangles, one with leg $h$ and hypotenuse $a$, and another one with corresponding leg $b/2$ and hypotenuse $r$. And of course $2rh=ab$ is equivalent to $4rA=abc$.

@GHfromMO : Good point!

@IosifPinelis regarding (i) We can assume the side giving the length c is from $(x_0,y_0)$ to $(-x_0,y_0)$ all points on the circle bellow the line  $y=y​​​_0+c/2$ and above the line $y=y​​​_0-c/2$ satisfy the inequality $ab<c$. Note that one of these lines do not intersect the unit circle, and thus we get circle segments and not pairs of circle segments.
I can clarify the end of the argument too, but If already this fails I’m not sure what is the point :)

I can follow your argument up to the final part (the paragraph with the smiley), but I don't think this final part works, at least without a lot of additional work to describe probabilities exactly. You use only the fact that for each circle segment there is a choice of  that attains it as a valid locus, but the same property would work also for ℎ</3, for instance.
